# Mudar background-position com Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom, antes de mais peço desculpa, mas esta pergunta é um bocado dificil de me expressar.

O que pretendo saber é se existe algum código em javascript que faça mexer o background-position muito rápido, até muito devagar e depois parar. Ou seja supomos que a animação demora 10 segundos. Inicialmente ele mexe muito rápido e vai abrandando até chegar ao 0 segundo e parar definitivamente.

Não sei se me fiz expressar muito bem, mas pretendo fazer isto com javascript ou jquery.

Meu Código:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

body,html,div {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
}

#anim {
  background:url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7a2c254d9e863db31614b95e909a9633?s=800&d=identicon') no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size:180% 180%;
}
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js">
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#anim').animate({'background-position-x': '100%'},8000,'easeOutCubic');
</script>
<div id="anim">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

O movimento seria a imagem da esquerda para a direita.

Não pretendo utilizar a animate do css, mas sim utilizar apenas javascript.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com jQuery fica simples:

```js
$('#anim').animate({'background-position-x': '100%'},8000,'easeOutCubic');
```

```css
body,html,div {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
}

#anim {
  background:url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7a2c254d9e863db31614b95e909a9633?s=800&d=identicon') no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size:300% 300%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<div id="anim"></div>
```

A velocidade é o segundo parâmetro, e desaceleração pode ser alterada no `easing`, que é um plugin do jQuery.

Comment: Onde está esse easing no codigo?

Comment: acrescentei uma explicação, e o endereço. Teste de novo no "executar", dei uma atualizada. Aumentei para 8 segundos (8000)

Comment: Aqui no stackoverflow está a funcionar exatamente como eu quero, porem eu tentei criar o arquivo e não está a funcionar. Adicionei o código a minha pergunta, pode-me informar o que fiz de errado? O efeito não funciona.

Comment: O que aconteceu quando vc testou no seu código? Nao apareceu, não animou, ou o que?

Comment: Apareceu somente a imagem, mas sem efeito.

Comment: Faltou fechar um script lá, mas nao sei se é isso

Comment: Fechei o script mas continua nao funcionando.

Comment: experimente por a parte do $( anim ) no fim do body pra ver se muda.

Comment: Já funciona, explique-me só porque ao fazer isso já passou a funcionar?

Comment: provavelmente pq quando o JS foi acionado o Anim ainda nao existia. Na verdade, o certo mesmo é executar o JS só depois do onload, mas isso vc tem que organizar para todos os JS da aplicação. Aí é um pouco mais complicado pra explicar aqui.

Comment: Para aumentar o tempo da animação e para aumentar uma maior velocidade mexo no background-position e no 8000 certo?

Comment: Numero de segundos desejados multiplicado por 1000. A velocidade só vai depender do tamanho da imagem real, isso depende do seu layout verdadeiro. A posição final depende do background-position-x.

Comment: Certo. Obrigado.

Comment: Lembre que se seu layout for fixo, você pode por os valores em px, em vez de usar % (mas ai realmente vc tem que ajustar e calcular)

Comment: Vou utilizar percentagem para ser igual para todos.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se a melhor maneira de "mover" uma imagem de fundo, seja modificar constantemente a posição do "background". Porem, se isso resolve seu problema, tem ai um exemplo:

CSS:

```
body{
    background-image: url('http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/smiley.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: 1px 1px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body></body>
```

JavaScript:

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var delay = 10;

var t = setTimeout( act , delay );

function act(){

    delay +=1;
    x++;
    y++;
    $('body').css('background-position',x+'px '+y+'px');

    clearInterval(t);
    t = setTimeout( act , delay );
}
```

Incluir:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" ></script>
```

Repare que o "delay" no intervalo é sempre incremento, isso para dar a impressão de que  imagem está perdendo velocidade, como você pediu. Para deixar o movimento constate, se quer verificar o quão rápido o background pode ser movido, comenta  a linha:

```
 //delay +=1;
```

Comment: Boa tarde, é basicamente isso, contudo tem como o efeito parar? definitivamente.

Comment: Sim, mas é preciso definir "quando". Basta em determinado momento não "agendar" o evento novamente, colocando uma verificação para checar se o critério de parada não foi atingido. if (!criterio){      t = setTimeout( act , delay ); }

Comment: Por exemplo, é possivel deixar a animação durante os 10 segundos, com a sensação que ta perdendo velocidade e ao segundo 0 parar completamente?